# How can I execute code from list or variable and get the result at Python?

Tags: python-3.x, code-generation

code

how it most work

```
from itertools import *
for i in combinations(["1","2","3"],3):
    print((''.join(i)))

result be 123
```

what i try do

```
from itertools import *
a = 'for i in combinations'
b = '(["1","2","3"],3):'
c = (a + b)
print (c)
eval (c)
print((''.join(i)))
```

error

```
    for i in combinations(["1","2","3"],3):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:/Terst111.py", line 6, in <module>
    eval (c)
  File "<string>", line 1
    for i in combinations(["1","2","3"],3):
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so i try put to a and b part of code line then i using c = a + b to create line. and then try execut it with eval and get result by join to i and print .

How make it work , what possible to do ? need for find fastest way of math solving

Comment: eval cannot evaluate for loops or similar nested structures

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to do by "generating code", but you could write the whole string to a Python file, then run that, and collect the output

Comment: This why i ask about another way , about write to file it's make slowdown. But i need at do it at fly , only problem how execute it , other problems like put best choises at list etc  is solved. How it can be used ? as bassik find best and fastest variant of math operation to get result at fly..

Comment: You can generate random lists of strings outside of the combinations call. You don't need to eval anything

Comment: combinations function is only as example for qustion , no mater what there , qustion is if exist any way to execute generated code and get result ...

Comment: Yes, like I said, run a file.

Comment: Problem is - write to file , read from file... ( so its be not generation "best way" at fly )

Comment: I dont understand what you're saying, but I am telling you that that is the only way to run the code you've asked for.